# Android Phonegap 2.1 > 2.2 Upgrade error

Tags: java, android, cordova, webview

I am working on a Phonegap app and saw that Phonegap has recently been updated to 2.2 with a lot of Android fixes. So I immediately updated by replacing the xml, jar, and JS file. My app used to work great. It's using a custom Javascript interface to add additional functionality. Unfortunately when upgraded to 2.2, I get the following error log:

[Pastebin error log](http://pastebin.com/N2ZW1Bzs)

This is the error I get when running the app on my Samsung Galaxy S2 running 4.0.4. This is the main application Java file I am using.

[Pastebin Java File](http://pastebin.com/tMat8PKj)

I hope you guys can help me spot the issue. I haven't got a clue on what might be causing the JNI Error.

**EDIT:** I tried the same code on an android 2.2 emulator and that gave me a more descriptive error:

```
10-31 13:02:12.945: I/dalvikvm(543): Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.<init>, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.<init>
10-31 13:02:12.945: W/dalvikvm(543): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 3298: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V
10-31 13:02:12.945: D/dalvikvm(543): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0001
10-31 13:02:12.945: D/dalvikvm(543): VFY: dead code 0x0004-005b in Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V
10-31 13:02:13.195: I/CordovaLog(543): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
10-31 13:02:13.205: I/CordovaLog(543): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
10-31 13:02:13.205: D/CordovaLog(543): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
10-31 13:02:13.205: I/CordovaLog(543): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
10-31 13:02:13.205: D/CordovaLog(543): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
10-31 13:02:13.215: W/CordovaWebView(543): useBrowserHistory=false is deprecated as of Cordova 2.2.0 and will be removed six months after the 2.2.0 release.  Please use the browser history and use history.back().
10-31 13:02:13.245: D/JsMessageQueue(543): Set native->JS mode to 2
10-31 13:02:13.245: I/CordovaWebView(543): Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge since Android version is old.
10-31 13:02:13.255: D/CordovaWebView(543): Origin to allow: http://127.0.0.1*
10-31 13:02:13.255: D/CordovaWebView(543): Unlimited access to network resources
10-31 13:02:13.265: D/CordovaWebView(543): Origin to allow: http://api.enkhuizenapp.nl
10-31 13:02:13.265: D/CordovaWebView(543): Origin to allow: .*
10-31 13:02:13.265: I/CordovaLog(543): Found log level DEBUG
10-31 13:02:13.265: I/CordovaLog(543): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
10-31 13:02:13.265: I/CordovaLog(543): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
10-31 13:02:13.265: D/CordovaLog(543): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
10-31 13:02:13.265: I/CordovaLog(543): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
10-31 13:02:13.265: D/CordovaLog(543): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
10-31 13:02:13.265: W/CordovaWebView(543): useBrowserHistory=false is deprecated as of Cordova 2.2.0 and will be removed six months after the 2.2.0 release.  Please use the browser history and use history.back().
10-31 13:02:13.285: D/JsMessageQueue(543): Set native->JS mode to 2
10-31 13:02:13.285: I/CordovaWebView(543): Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge since Android version is old.
10-31 13:02:13.285: D/CordovaWebView(543): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/menu.html)
10-31 13:02:13.285: D/PluginManager(543): init()
10-31 13:02:13.296: D/CordovaWebView(543): >>> loadUrlNow()
10-31 13:02:13.296: D/CordovaWebView(543): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/main.html)
10-31 13:02:13.296: D/PluginManager(543): init()
10-31 13:02:13.315: D/CordovaWebView(543): >>> loadUrlNow()
10-31 13:02:13.955: D/dalvikvm(543): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1775 objects / 133528 bytes in 76ms
10-31 13:02:14.765: D/Cordova(543): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/menu.html)
10-31 13:02:15.365: D/Cordova(543): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/main.html)
10-31 13:02:15.685: I/Database(543): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
10-31 13:02:15.945: D/CordovaLog(543): Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing.
10-31 13:02:15.955: D/CordovaLog(543): file:///android_asset/www/scripts/cordova-2.2.0.js: Line 1032 : Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing.
10-31 13:02:15.955: I/Web Console(543): Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. at file:///android_asset/www/scripts/cordova-2.2.0.js:1032
10-31 13:02:16.065: D/AndroidRuntime(543): Shutting down VM
10-31 13:02:16.065: W/dalvikvm(543): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin.execute(Plugin.java:74)
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:61)
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:224)
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:43)
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onJsPrompt(CordovaChromeClient.java:213)
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:566)
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-31 13:02:16.075: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bug raised: (CB-1810) CordovaWebView does not work as a component, go add your info. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1810

Comment: I think Joe has already fixed it. You may need to grab the edge code and build your own jar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a current workaround for this issue, and that is that you add a thread pool to your CordovaActivity:

```
private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

And of course, implement the newly added getThreadPool() method.  This was added by accident, and will hopefully be encapsulated in the next release somehow.

```
public ExecutorService getThreadPool()
{
    return threadPool;
}
```

Comment: How will people using phonegap build get around this?

Comment: @drogon: As far as I know, people with PhoneGap Build can't even use CordovaWebView as a component and won't run into this issue.  This is only for those who choose to use it as a component as part of a larger Android app.

Answer (score -1):

I had that problem, but after following the steps described in the docs [Upgrading Cordova Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_upgrading_android_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20Android), that error disappeared.