# Phonegap on android issue

Tags: javascript, android, backbone.js, cordova

in developing my app by backbone.js in eclipse logcat I can see this warn:

```
unable to resolve direct method 3220: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.<init>  
(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V
```

I've no idea what is it!

Answer (score 1):

Check this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194537/android-phonegap-2-1-2-2-upgrade-error).

This guy had a similar issue and was fixed with a workaround. It might help you.

Hope it helps!